# disable links in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In my case I want to link the user

```
 #/page/{{type}}/{{uservalue}}
```

The type is a radio button and uservalue is something the user wrote. How do I make this link not clickable until both values have been specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define link click handler in scope:

```
$scope.gotoUser = function (event, type, uservalue) {
  if (event) event.preventDefault();
  if (type && uservalue) {
    $location.path('/user/' + type + '/' + uservalue);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And then in html:

```
<a ng-click="gotoUser($event, type, uservalue)"></a>
```

Maybe someone can guess better approach with preserving link `href` attribute.